# List Index Out of Range, Why Is This Happening?

Tags: python, list

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\cloud.py", line 34, in <module>
    c = Cloud()
  File "E:\python\cloud.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.cweaponAttack = self.weaponAttack[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm having trouble with my code and I have checked for spelling errors everywhere but I haven't found any.

```
class Cloud:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weaponAttack = list()
        self.cweaponAttack = self.weaponAttack[0]
        self.sp = 1
        self.armor = list()
        self.armorReduction = list()
        self.weapon = list()
        self.cweapon = self.weapon
        self.money = 10000
        self.lvl = 0
        self.exp = 0
        self.mexp = 100
        self.attackPower = 0
        addaps = self.cweaponAttack * self.attackPower
        self.dmg = self.cweaponAttack + addaps
        self.hp = 100
        self.mhp = 100
        self.name = "Cloud"
c = Cloud()
armors = ["No Armor","Belice Armor","Yoron's Armor","Andrew's Custom Armor","Zeus' Armor"]
armorReduce = [0, .025, .05, .10, .15]
c.armor.append(armors[0])
c.armorReduction.append(armorReduce[0])
w = random.randint(0, 10)
weapons = ["The Sword of Wizdom","The Sword of Kindness", "The Sword of Power", "The Sword of Elctricity", "The Sword of Fire", "The Sword of Wind", "The Sword of Ice", "The Sword of Self Appreciation", "The Sword of Love", "The Earth Sword", "The Sword of The Universe"]
weaponAttacks = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
c.weapon.append(weapons[w])
c.weaponAttack.append(weaponAttacks[w])
print("You have recieved the ", weapons[w])
print("")
print("It does ", weaponAttacks[w]," attack power!")
print("")
```

The lines above is where i'm positive that the error is coming from, but just in case, here's the rest of the code. Warning: It's very long.

```
import random
import time
import sys
def asky():
    ask = input("Would you like to check you player stats and inventory or go to the next battle? Say inventory for inventory or say next for the next battle: ")
    if "inventory" in ask:
        inventory()
    elif "next" in ask:
        user()
def Type(t):
    t = list(t)
    for a in t:
        sys.stdout.write(a)
        time.sleep(.035)
class Cloud:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weaponAttack = list()
        self.cweaponAttack = self.weaponAttack[0]
        self.sp = 1
        self.armor = list()
        self.armorReduction = list()
        self.weapon = list()
        self.cweapon = self.weapon
        self.money = 10000
        self.lvl = 0
        self.exp = 0
        self.mexp = 100
        self.attackPower = 0
        addaps = self.cweaponAttack * self.attackPower
        self.dmg = self.cweaponAttack + addaps
        self.hp = 100
        self.mhp = 100
        self.name = "Cloud"
c = Cloud()
armors = ["No Armor","Belice Armor","Yoron's Armor","Andrew's Custom Armor","Zeus' Armor"]
armorReduce = [0, .025, .05, .10, .15]
c.armor.append(armors[0])
c.armorReduction.append(armorReduce[0])
w = random.randint(0, 10)
weapons = ["The Sword of Wizdom","The Sword of Kindness", "The Sword of Power", "The Sword of Elctricity", "The Sword of Fire", "The Sword of Wind", "The Sword of Ice", "The Sword of Self Appreciation", "The Sword of Love", "The Earth Sword", "The Sword of The Universe"]
weaponAttacks = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
c.weapon.append(weapons[w])
c.weaponAttack.append(weaponAttacks[w])
print("You have recieved the ", weapons[w])
print("")
print("It does ", weaponAttacks[w]," attack power!")
print("")
class Soldier:
    def __init__(self):
        dmg = random.randint(5,20)
        self.lvl = 0
        self.attackPower = dmg
        self.hp = 100
        self.mhp = 100
        self.name = "Soldier"
s = Soldier()
def enemy():
    ad = random.randint(0,2)
    if ad >= 1: #Attack
        Type("Soldier attacks!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        hm = random.randint(0, 2)
        if hm == 0:
            Type("Miss!")
            print("")
        elif hm > 0:
            crit = random.randint(0,10)
            if crit == 0:
                print("CRITICAL HIT!")
                crithit = int((s.attackPower) * (.5))
                c.hp = c.hp - (s.attackPower + crithit)
            elif crit >= 1:
                c.hp = c.hp - s.attackPower
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            asky()
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
        else:
            user()
    elif ad == 0:#Defend
        Type("Soldier Defends!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        if s.hp == s.mhp:
            print("")
        elif s.hp > (s.mhp - 15) and s.hp < s.mhp:
            add = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = add + s.hp
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        elif s.hp < (s.mhp - 15):
            s.hp = s.hp + 15
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            asky()
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
        else:
            user()
def user():
    User = input("attack or defend? ")
    if "attack" in User:#attack
        Type("Cloud attacks!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        hm = random.randint(0,4)
        if hm == 0:
            Type("Miss!")
            print("")
        elif hm > 0:
            crit = random.randint(0,7)
            if crit == 0:
                print("CRITICAL HIT!")
                crithit = int((c.dmg) * (.5))
                s.hp = s.hp - (c.dmg + crithit)
            elif crit >= 1:
                s.hp = s.hp - c.dmg
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
            asky()
        else:
            enemy()
    elif "defend" in User:#defend
        Type("Cloud Heals!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        if c.hp == c.mhp:
            Type("You are at the maximum amount of health. Cannot add more health.")
            print("")
        elif c.hp > (c.mhp - 15) and c.hp < c.mhp:
            add = c.mhp - c.hp
            c.hp = add + c.hp
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        elif c.hp <= (c.mhp - 15):
            c.hp = c.hp + 15
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("Congratulations!")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
            asky()
        else:
            enemy()
    else:
        Type("The option you have entered is not in the game database. Please try again")
        print("")
        user()
def inventory():
    if c.exp == c.mexp:
        print("LEVEL UP!")
        c.exp = 0
        adde = int((c.mexp) * (.5))
        c.mexp = c.mexp + adde
        c.sp = c.sp + 1
        c.lvl = c.lvl + 1
        if c.lvl > s.lvl:
            s.lvl = s.lvl + 1
        print("")
        print("")
        print("Level: ", c.lvl)
        print("")
        nextlvl = c.lvl + 1
        print("Experience: [", c.exp, "/", c.mexp, "]level", nextlvl)
        print("")
        print("Amount of Skill Points:", c.sp)
        print("")
        for i in range(0, len(c.weapon)):
            print(i)
            print("Weapon: ", c.weapon[i])
            print("Weapon Attack Damage: ", c.weaponAttack[i])
            print("")
        for j in range(0, len(c.armor)):
            print("Armor: ", c.armor[j])
            print("Armor Damage Reduction: ", c.armorReduction[j])
            print("")
        print("Amount of Crystals: ", c.money)
        print("")
        print("")
        print("Stats:")
        print("")
        print("Maximum Health: ", c.mhp)
        print("")
        print("Current Health: ", c.hp)
        print("")
        dtop = 100 * c.attackPower
        print("Attack Power: Adds", dtop, "% of sword damage")
        print("")
        print("Overall Damage: ", c.dmg)
        print("")
        print("Your Name: ", c.name)
        print("")
        print("")
        sn = input("To heal yourself, you need to go to the shop. Say, *shop* to go to the shop, say  *name* to change your name, say, *next* to fight another battle, say, *level* to use your skill point(s), or say, *help* for help: ")
        print("")
        if "name" in sn:
            c.name = input("Enter Your name here: ")
            print("Success! Your name has been changed to ", c.name)
            inventory()
        elif "weapon" in sn:
            weapChange()
        elif "next" in sn:
            Type("3")
            print("")
            Type("2")
            print("")
            Type("1")
            print("")
            Type("FIGHT!")
            print("")
            user()
        elif "help" in sn:
            def helpp():
                Type("The goal of this game is to fight all the enemies, kill the miniboss, and       finally, kill the boss! each time you kill an enemy you gain *crystals*,        currency which you can use to buy weapons, armor, and health. You can spend     these *crystals* at the shop. To go to the shop, just say *shop* when you are in your inventory. Although, each time you level up, they get harder to            defeat. Once you level up, you gain one skill point. This skill point is then   used while in your inventory by saying the word *level*. You can use your skill point(s) to upgrade your stats, such as, your maximum health, and your attack   power.")
                print("")
                continu = input("Say, *back*, to go back to your inventory screen. ")
                if "back" in continu:
                    inventory()
                else:
                    Type("The word you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
                    print("")
                    helpp()
        elif "shop" in sn:
            shop()
        elif "level" in sn:
            skills()
    else:
        print("Level: ", c.lvl)
        print("")
        nextlvl = c.lvl + 1
        print("Experience: [", c.exp, "/", c.mexp, "]level", nextlvl)
        print("")
        print("Amount of Skill Points:", c.sp)
        print("")
        for i in range(0, len(c.weapon)):
            print("Weapon:", c.weapon[i])
            print("")
            print("Weapon Attack Damage: ", c.weaponAttack[i])
            print("")
        for i in range(0, len(c.armor)):
            print("Armor: ", c.armor[i])
            print("")
            print("Armor Damage Reduction: ", c.armorReduction[i])
            print("")
        print("Amount of Crystals: ", c.money)
        print("")
        print("")
        print("Stats:")
        print("")
        print("Maximum Health: ", c.mhp)
        print("")
        print("Current Health: ", c.hp)
        print("")
        dtop = 100 * c.attackPower
        print("Attack Power: Adds", dtop, "% of sword damage")
        print("")
        print("Your Name: ", c.name)
        print("")
        print("")
        sn = input("To heal yourself, you need to go to the shop. Say, *shop* to go to the shop, say  *name* to change your name, say, *next* to fight another battle, say, *level* to use your skill point(s), say, *weapon* to switch your current weapon, or say, *help* for help: ")
        if "name" in sn:
            c.name = input("Enter Your name here: ")
            print("Success! Your name has been changed to ", c.name)
            inventory()
        elif "weapon" in sn:
            weapChange()
        elif "next" in sn:
            Type("3")
            print("")
            Type("2")
            print("")
            Type("1")
            print("")
            Type("FIGHT!")
            print("")
            user()
        elif "help" in sn:
            def helpp():
                Type("The goal of this game is to fight all the enemies, kill the miniboss, and       finally, kill the boss! each time you kill an enemy you gain *crystals*,        currency which you can use to buy weapons, armor, and health. You can spend     these *crystals* at the shop. To go to the shop, just say *shop* when you are in your inventory. Although, each time you level up, they get harder to            defeat. Once you level up, you gain one skill point. This skill point is then   used while in your inventory by saying the word *level*. You can use your skill point(s) to upgrade your stats, such as, your maximum health, and your attack   power. To switch out your weapons, type in, *weapon*.")
                print("")
                continu = input("Say, *back*, to go back to your inventory screen. ")
                if "back" in continu:
                    inventory()
                else:
                    Type("The word you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
                    print("")
                    helpp()
            helpp()
        elif "shop" in sn:
            shop()
        elif "level" in sn:
            skills()
def weapChange():
    for i in range(0, len(c.weapon)):
        print("Weapon:", "To equip", c.weapon[i], ",say", i)
        print("Weapon Attack Damage: ", c.weaponAttack[i])
        print("")
    weapchoice = input("Enter the weapon ID to the sword you would like to equip, or say, *cancel*, to go back to your inventory. ")
    print("")
    if "0" in weapchoice:
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[0]
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[0]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[0], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "1" in weapchoice:
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[1]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[1], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[1]
    elif "2" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[2]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[2]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[2], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "3" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[3]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[3]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[3], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "4" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[4]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[4]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[4], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "5" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[5]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[5]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[5], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "6" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[6]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[6]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[6], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "7" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[7]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[7]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[7], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "8" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[8]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[8]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[8], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "9" in weapchoice:
        c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[9]
        c.cweapon = c.weapon[9]
        print("Success!", c.weapon[9], "is now equipped!")
        inventory()
    elif "cancel" in weapchoice:
        inventory()
    else:
        Type("The word or number you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
        print("")
        print("")
        weapChange()
def skills():
    print("")
    print("You have", c.sp, "skill points to use.")
    print("")
    print("Upgrade attack power *press the number 1*")
    print("")
    print("Upgrade maximum health *press the number 2*")
    print("")
    skill = input("Enter the number of the skill you wish to upgrade, or say, cancel, to go back to your inventory screen. ")
    print("")
    if "1" in skill:
        sure = input("Are you sure you want to upgrade your character attack power in return for 1    skill point? *yes or no* ")
        print("")
        if "yes" in sure:
            if c.sp == 0:
                Type("I'm sorry but you do not have sufficient skill points to upgrade your attack    power. ")
                print("")
                skills()
            elif c.sp >= 1:
                c.sp = c.sp - 1
                c.attackPower = float(c.attackPower + .1)
                addsap = int(100 * c.attackPower)
                print("Your attack power has been upgraded to deal", addsap, "% more damage")
                skills()
            else:
                Type("How the fuck did you get negative skill points?! ")
                print("")
                skills()
        if "no" in sure:
            skills()
    elif "2" in skill:
        sure = input("Are you sure you want to upgrade your maximum health in return for 1 skill      point? *yes or no* ")
        print("")
        if "yes" in sure:
            if c.sp == 0:
                Type("I'm sorry but you do not have sufficient skill points to upgrade your maximum   health. ")
                print("")
                skills()
            elif c.sp >= 1:
                c.sp = c.sp - 1
                c.mhp = c.mhp + 30
                skills()
            else:
                Type("How the fuck did you get negative skill points?! ")
                print("")
                skills()
        if "no" in sure:
            skills()
    elif "cancel" in skill:
        inventory()
    else:
        Type("The word or number you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
        print("")
        skills()
def shop():
    print("")
    Type("Welcome to Andrew's Blacksmith! Here you will find all the weapons, armor, and  health you need, to defeat the horrid beast who goes by the name of Murlor! ")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Who's Murlor? *To ask this question, type in the number 1*")
    print("")
    print("Can you heal me? *To ask this question, type in the number 2*")
    print("")
    print("What weapons do you have? *To ask this question, type in the number 3*")
    print("")
    print("Got any armor? *To ask this question, type in the number 4*")
    print("")
    ask1 = input("Enter desired number here or say, cancel, to go back to your inventory screen. ")
    print("")
    if "1" in ask1:
        def murlor():
            Type("Murlor is a devil-like creature that lives deep among the caves of Bricegate. He has been terrorising the people of this village for centuries.")
            print("")
            print("")
            print("What is Bricegate? *To choose this option, type in the number 1*")
            print("")
            print("Got any more information about this village? *To choose this option, type in the number 2*")
            print("")
            print("Thank you! *To choose this option, type in the number 3*")
            print("")
            ask3 = input("Enter desired number here, or say, cancel, to go back to the main shop screen. ")
            print("")
            if "1" in ask3:
                def questionTown():
                    Type("That's the name of this town.")
                    print("")
                    print("")
                    town = input("Go back? *Say, yes, to go back to the previous screen*")
                    print("")
                    if "yes" in town:
                        murlor()
                    else:
                        Type("I'm sorry but the word you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        questionTown()
                questionTown()
            elif "2" in ask3:
                def askquest1():
                    Type("Well I DO know that there's this secret underground dungeon. It's VERY dangerous but it comes with a huge reward. If you ever consider it, could you get my lucky axe? I dropped it down a hole leading to the dungeon and i was too afraid to  get it back. *If you accept the quest, say yes, if you want to go back, say,    no.*")
                    quest1 = input(" ")
                    print("")
                    if "yes" in quest1:
                        quest1()
                    elif "no" in quest1:
                        murlor()
                    else:
                        Type("The option you have selected is not valid. Please try again")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        askquest1()
                askquest1()
            elif "3" in ask3:
                shop()
            else:
                Type("The number or word you have entered is invalid. please try again.")
                print("")
                print("")
                murlor()
        murlor()
    elif "2" in ask1:
        def heal():
            if c.hp == c.mhp:
                Type("I can't heal you because there's nothing to heal.")
                print("")
                print("")
                shop()
            elif c.hp > 10 and c.hp < c.mhp:
                Type("Sure! That'll be 30 crystals.")
                ask2 = input(" *say, okay, to confirm the purchase or say, no, to cancel the pruchase* ")
                print("")
                if "okay" in ask2:
                    if c.money < 30:
                        Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        shop()
                    elif c.money >= 30:
                        c.money = c.money - 30
                        Type("30 crystals has been removed from your inventory.")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        addn = c.mhp - c.hp
                        c.hp = c.hp + addn
                        Type("You have been healed!")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        shop()
                elif "no" in ask2:
                    shop()
                else:
                    Type("The option you have chosen is invalid. Please try again")
                    print("")
                    print("")
                    heal()
            elif c.hp > 0 and c.hp <= 10:
                Type("How are you still alive?!")
                print("")
                print("")
                Type("That'll be 50 crystals.")
                ask2 = input(" *say, okay, to confirm the purchase or say, no, to cancel the pruchase* ")
                print("")
                if "okay" in ask2:
                    if c.money < 30:
                        Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        shop()
                    elif c.money >= 30:
                        c.money = c.money - 30
                        Type("30 crystals has been removed from your inventory.")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        addn = c.mhp - c.hp
                        c.hp = c.hp + addn
                        Type("You have been healed!")
                        print("")
                        print("")
                        shop()
                elif "no" in ask2:
                    shop()
                else:
                    Type("The option you have chosen is invalid. Please try again")
                    print("")
                    print("")
                    heal()
            else:
                Type("HELP!! IT'S THE WALKING DEAD!!")
                print("")
                print("")
                shop()
        heal()
user()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Cloud:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weaponAttack = list()
        self.cweaponAttack = self.weaponAttack[0]
```

You set `self.weaponAttack` to be an *empty* list, and then try to assign `cweaponAttack` to be the element at index `0` in `weaponAttack` - empty lists don't have anything at index 0, as they are empty. I'm guessing you want `self.cweaponAttack` to be nothing when a new `Cloud` instance is created, in which case if you need it to be nothing you can set it to be `None`, else you can just assign to it when needed.

```
self.cweaponAttack = None
```

Comment: yes but when I want self.cweaponAttack to be equal to the index 0 of self.weaponAttack would i just do c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[0]?

Comment: @dirtydan Yes, you would just assign to it normally.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the instance of the class is first created with `Cloud()`, `self.weaponAttack` is an empty `list`, and there will be no such thing as an index 0.

You may consider passing a non-empty list to `self.weaponAttack` as an argument via the class constructor:

```
weaponAttacks = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
c = Cloud(weaponAttacks)
```

And your `class` becomes:

```
class Cloud:
    '''This is the Cloud class etc.'''

    weaponAttack = list()
    def __init__(self, weaponAttacks):
        self.weaponAttack = weaponAttacks
        self.cweaponAttack = self.weaponAttack[0]
```

Comment: yes but when I want self.cweaponAttack to be equal to the index 0 of self.weaponAttack would i just do c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[0]?

Comment: it is already done in the `class` constructor: `self.cweaponAttack = self.weaponAttack[0]`, so `c.cweaponAttack` will return the item at index 0 of `weaponAttack`

Comment: oh thank you! This error delayed me about 2 days and I didn't want to be such a nuisance and ask stackoverflow again but it was my only resort. Thank you

Comment: We're glad to help. That's what stackoverflow was built for ;)

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'weaponAttacks'

Comment: yes but when i do that and i print out c.weaponAttack, c.cweaponAttack it will always give me the first number in the list and i set "w" to randomize which weapon attack i get to go with the sword. for instance, i get index number 5 as "w", the attack power of the sword in index 5 will be c.weaponAttack[5] or in my case that would be c.weapon.append(weapons[w]) and c.weaponAttack.append(weaponAttacks[w])

Answer (score 1):

```
self.weaponAttack = list()
self.cweaponAttack = self.weaponAttack[0]
```

At the time of the second line, `self.weaponAttack`is an empty list, and therefore doesn't have any elements. Hence, an index of 0 is out of range for `self.weaponAttack`.

Comment: yes but when I want self.cweaponAttack to be equal to the index 0 of self.weaponAttack would i just do c.cweaponAttack = c.weaponAttack[0]?